# mostrar consulta de mysql con checkbox php javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Buenas tardes tengo un codigo en php donde una lista tiene valores de un campo de mysql:

```
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Ruta: </span>
      <select name="rutas" id="estados" value="0" class="form-control" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <?php
          while ($fil = mysqli_fetch_array($resultas)){  ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $fil['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fil['descripcion']; ?></option>

          <?php 
        } ?>
        </select>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <a href="rutas/nuevaRuta.php" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>
  </span>
  </div>
```

Donde los datos salen de la siguiente consulta:

```
 $resultas = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM rutas WHERE (cveorig='$claveEstado' OR cvedest='$claveEstado') AND cliente='CLI140002'");
```

lo que necesito es hacer una consulta general (mostrar todos los registros del campo descripción) al dar click en un checkbox

Comment: quieres que se aga la consulta al momento de seleccionar un diferente option o eso el lo que entiendo y por lo que veo en tu codigo que presentas es correcto

Comment: Al inicio el select es el resultado de una consulta determinada, lo que quiero hacer es que al dar clic en un checbox cambie la consulta a solo SELECT * FROM rutas; pero no se como hacerlo ya que debe de estar en la misma pagina el checkbo y el select

Comment: No veo el checkbox

Comment: lo que observo es que; Al parecer tienes un checkbox y este mismo quieres que recupere los nuevos datos, cierto?

Comment: asi es, el select que tengo muestra solo algunos resultados de la consulta, lo que necesito es que al dar click me muestre todos los registros de la tabla rutas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu problema es que no sabes como actualizar la consulta `sql` al activar el `checkbox`, si es así, te recomiendo usar `JS` o `Jquery` y cargar los datos de forma asíncrona, es decir, en lugar de esto:

```
<select name="rutas" id="estados" value="0" class="form-control" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <?php
      while ($fil = mysqli_fetch_array($resultas)){  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fil['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fil['descripcion']; ?></option>
      <?php 
    } ?>
</select>
```

Intenta cargar por ejemplo con `jquery`:

```
$('#id_checkbox').change(function () {
  $.post(url_backend, params)
   .done(function (data) {
     //recorrer el resultado, recomendado retornar json desde el server
     $.each(data, function(i, item) {
       $('#estados').append($('<option>', {
         value: item.value,
         text: item.text
       }));
     });
   });
}
```

Y repite esto cuando carga el `dom` para cargar la primera consulta del `select`.

**Edit**: Recuerda resetear el `select` porque el `append` agrega el elemento al final del contenido del `select`.

Comment: en la segunda linea del jQuery es mandar por post un valor a un archivo donde realizo mi consulta?

Comment: En esa linea haces la petición al servidor, puedes mandar o no parámetros eso depende de tus necesidades.